# Limit number of lines displayed in a table by wordpress (php(

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a table in wordpress which keeps being longer and longer.

I would like to set a limit, so only the last 250 results are shown or only the last 30days. Whatever simpler.

This code come from the Wordpress Affiliate Manager Plugin

```
    <p><?php printf(__( 'Displaying %1$d of %2$d impressions', 'wpam' ), count($this->viewData['impressions']), $this->viewData['impressionCount']); ?></p>

    <table class="widefat">
        <thead>
        <tr>
             <th width="25"><?php _e( 'ID', 'wpam' ) ?></th>
             <th width="200"><?php _e( 'Date Occurred', 'wpam' ) ?></th>
             <th width="100"><?php _e( 'Creative', 'wpam' ) ?></th>
             <th><?php _e( 'Referrer', 'wpam' ) ?></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        $creativeNames = $this->viewData['creativeNames'];

        foreach ( $this->viewData['impressions'] as $impression ) {
        ?>
        <tr class="impression">
            <td><?php echo $impression->impressionId?></td>
            <td><?php echo date("m/d/Y H:i:s", $impression->dateCreated)?></td>
            <td><?php echo $creativeNames[$impression->sourceCreativeId]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $impression->referer?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
     if ( ! count( $this->viewData['impressions'] ) ):
    ?>
         <div class="daterange-form"><p><?php _e( 'No records found for the date range selected.', 'wpam' ) ?></p></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there's an option on the plugin for limiting the impressions number. If there isn't, you can limit it by slicing the array with `array_slice`, like this:

```
<?php
    $creativeNames = $this->viewData['creativeNames'];
    $impressions = array_slice($this->viewData['impressions'], 0, 250);

    foreach ( $impressions as $impression ) {
?>
<tr class="impression">
    <!-- your code -->
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

If you need only the last 250, you can combine it with `array_reverse`:

```
$impressions = array_slice(array_reverse($this->viewData['impressions']), 0, 250);
```